# Under what conditions does $L^{1}(X)$ have a predual?

Tags: banach-spaces, dual-spaces

I know this question has been asked a million times—but they seem to always be with some special flair. I've looked at many and cannot extract from them an answer to my plain question:

**Question:** Let $(X,\mu)$ be a topological space endowed with a regular Borel measure. Consider the Banach space $\left(L^{1}(X,\mu),~\|\cdot\|_{1}\right)$. What do $X$ and $\mu$ have to satisfy (sufficient would be okay, but necessary-and-sufficient better), so that $L^{1}(X,\mu)$ has a predual?

**Note:** I don't care at this stage if the predual is separable.

**Note:** I am fully aware of papers that exist, that show what a Banach space $Y$ has to satisfy so that $\exists{X,\mu:~}Y^{\prime}\cong L^{1}(X,\mu)$. However I am asking the reverse: Given $(X,\mu)$ when does such a $Y$ exist?

Does $\mu$ have to be finite? Does $X$ have to be separable? Does $\mu$ have to have only finitely many atoms? *etc.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Diestel and Uhl's *Vector Measures*, it's shown that for finite $\mu$, unless $\mu$ is purely atomic, the space $L_1(\mu)$ is not isomorphic to a dual space. See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243715/is-the-l1-space-dual-to-a-banach-space/243737), also.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks! The proof via the unit ball of $L^{1}(\mu)$ having no extreme points (if $\mu$ is not purely atomic), whereas the unit ball of a dual space being convex & weak* compact always does (Krein-Milman), is an elegant explanation. … Damned $L^{1}$, making all our proofs inconvenient! : )